# zend framework + core php integration

Tags: php, zend-framework, legacy

I have to convert a site in zend framework. Site is big I can't convert the site at a time in zend It will take abt 6 months. Is it possible that I update it module by module (parts)  and keep on uploading in live site so some module of my site will run on zend and some on core php. Can I do any setting for url in zend framework so both on my url can work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

partially migrating onto a/another framework is strongly discouraged. Don't mess with live-sites (especially not big ones) unless you really(!) need to. You should better set up a testing/migration site in your local office and do a full migration, and thorough testing, before you release anything into the wild.

If you really want to do this you should start looking into .htaccess conditional request rewriting to redirect the request either to zend or to your proprietary PHP application.

Cheers,
haggi

Comment: Thnaks,

pls give me example rules to write in .htaccess

Comment: You can find the official docs here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html